# Deployed React Front-End not Communicating Node Back-End - Cpanel Configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cpanel

So I have a React frontend, and Node backend as my api connecting to mysql database.  Everything works perfectly locally.

Now I have deployed to a c-panel VPS.

Front end loads as it should.
The back-end is listening, and prints out the data as it should if I type my IP address with routes into the address bar on a browswer.

However, I can get it to work typing the "domain-name + the routes".  Can anyone tell me what's going on, and how to configure this is cPanel properly?  I've spent days going in circles on this, and the hosting company support is no help at all.

here is a sample fetch call:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/clients/all')
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    clients: result.sort((a, b) => a.client.localeCompare(b.client)),
                });
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(
                fetch(`/api/contacts/all`)
                    .then(res => {
                        if (!res.ok) {
                            throw new Error();
                        }
                        return res.json();
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        this.setState({ contacts: result });
                        console.log(result);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            );
    }
```

This is my server file with the routes in it.... I can't understand where my configuration is wrong. I think it may even be some cpanel configuration with the server, and not necessarily my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host        : 'localhost',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : 'C5pkhi6r12!',
    database    : 'ppr'
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

app.get('/api/clients/all', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'handbook' table).
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM clients", function (error, results) {
            // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
            if (error) throw error;

            // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is where the data is.
            console.log(results);
            res.json(results);
        });
        connection.release();
    });
});

app.get('/api/contacts/all', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'handbook' table).
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM contacts", function (error, results) {
            // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
            if (error) throw error;

            // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is where the data is.
            // console.log(results);
            res.json(results);
        });
        connection.release();
    });
});


// Starting our server.
app.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0",  () => {
    console.log('Listening on port http://localhost:8080');
});
```

Comment: Hey just wanna ask a few questions to clear up things,
Are you using react router dom in your client,
Are you using a proxy to call the api from the client,
Are you serving the built version of the react app from the node app

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873001/9285308 for how you should serve the client from the backend

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer, but this is how I did.

1. Add "Hostname": "https://YOURDOMAIN.XYZ" to package.json in react app.
2. Build your react app, and upload it to public_html
3. Use nodejs tool of cpanel.
4. Don't do app.listen(port, ........). Just use callback or leave it to `app.listen()`

Comment: This doesn't works as I am facing the same problem. Any more suggestions?