# Why can't I call localhost localhost:5000 from localhost:3000 using axios in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I have a react application running on `localhost:3000` and in that I am making a **GET** request in my code using axios to `http://localhost:5000/fblogin`.

```js
const Login = () => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/fblogin",
  };
  axios.request(options)
  .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
  });
};
```

But I'm getting a error having status `(failed)net::ERR_FAILED` initiator `xhr177`.
How can I resolve it

Comment: You need to implement CORS on the 5000 app endpoint since it is a cross origin request

Comment: If the app is running on port 3000 you need to run another app on port 5000 but if it's the same app it can't get what's on 5000 if it's already runs on 3000

Comment: @charlietfl can you please guide me through how to implement CORS policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to 1. implement express cors, and 2. add a proxy from react to your server

[1] https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```sh
npm install cors
```

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

[2] https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

In your react's `package.json`, add

```json
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Note that this will work in development only.

For production, you'll need to serve the client from the server.
See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

/**
 * add your API routes here to avoid them getting overtaken
 * by the statically served client
*/

/**
 * add this as the last handler
*/
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    const pathToClientBuild = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'path', 'to', 'client', 'build');
    app.use(express.static(pathToClientBuild));

    /**
     * experiment with '/' and '/*' and see what works best for you
    */
    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(pathToClientBuild, 'index.html'));
    });
}

app.listen(5000);
```

(and to make it work, you'll need to build the client first, and then serve the server with `NODE_ENV=production node ./server.js`).

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Login 9636634272 = () => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/fblogin",
  };
  axios.request(options)
  .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
  });
};
```

```js
const Login = () => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/fblogin",
  };
  axios.request(options)
  .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.